# Как пользоваться оператором if в JS?

Tags: javascript

> Создать глобальную переменную senseOfLife = 42. создать функцию, которая будет принимать параметр otherSenseOfLife. Если параметр передать, то функция должна вернуть его. А если не передать, то Фунция должен вернуть глобальную переменную senseOfLife.

```
 var senseOfLife = 42;

 function showVariable (otherSenseOfLife) {
   if (otherSenseOfLife == 42);

   return senseOfLife;
 }
 showVariable();
```

Answer (score 2):

Здесь не выполняется задача

> Если параметр передать, то функция должна вернуть его.

Вместо этого проверяется странное условие

```
if (otherSenseOfLife==42);
```

и если оно выполняется - ничего не делается.

При этом всегда возвращается значение глобальной переменной.

Вместо этого нужно было вернуть саму переменную `otherSenseOfLife`.

Для проверки количества переданных параметров можно воспользоваться свойством `length` объекта [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)

```js
var senseOfLife = 42;

function showVariable(otherSenseOfLife) {
  if (arguments.length > 0)
    return otherSenseOfLife;

  return senseOfLife;
}
console.log(showVariable());
console.log(showVariable(1));
```

Comment: а так: `return otherSenseOfLife ? otherSenseOfLife : senseOfLife; ` будет не проще?

Comment: @Bald, не проще в случае `showVariable(0)` например :-) Условие можно заменить на тернарный оператор, но не всегда нужно :)

Comment: в случае с `showVariable(0)` будет возвращен 0 как и должен, спасибо за пример с проверкой существования аргументов, сам бы не сообразил

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно проверить, передан ли аргумент в функцию, а вы проверяете его значение. Если аргумент не был передан в функцию, то он будет содержать `undefined`

```
var senseOfLife = 42;

function showVariable (otherSenseOfLife) {

    // если функцию вызвали без аргументов showVariable();
    if (otherSenseOfLife == undefined) {
        return senseOfLife;
    }

    // если функцию вызвали с аргументом, например, showVariable(684);
    return otherSenseOfLife;
}

showVariable(); // Вернет 42
showVariable(8); // Вернет 8
```

Comment: но `undefined` тоже можно передать :-) `showVariable(undefined)` :)

Answer (score 2):

Современный JavaScript позволяет использовать в функциях [параметры по умолчанию](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters):

```js
var senseOfLife = 42;

function showVariable(otherSenseOfLife = senseOfLife) {
  return otherSenseOfLife;
}

console.log(showVariable());
console.log(showVariable(43));
```

То есть если параметр не передан, ему будет присвоено значение переменной `senseOfLife`.

Comment: добавь описание, что происходит в коде, можно добавить ссылку на справку о [Параметрах по умолчанию](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters)